# How do I remove a qos from an account in Slurm

Tags: linux, scheduler, slurm, system-administration

I have a system with a slurm scheduler. I have account which has access to a particular qos, and I would like to remove it from the account.

What is the command?

I have tried leaving the qos off, with this command, but it doesn't work and says I haven't given sacctmgr anything to set

`sacctmgr modify account name=acc_name qos=`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a specific QOS with the `-=` operator, as mentioned in the [examples](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacctmgr.html#SECTION_EXAMPLES):

```
sacctmgr modify account where name=acc_name set qos-=QOS_name
```